# Can't connect to Amazon RDS from Docker container

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, boot2docker, rds

I've created a Docker container which is running fine, except the part where I want to connect to an Amazon RDS instance.

I can connect fine from my MySQL Client and the RDS instance is running fine.

Somehow I can't connect from my Docker Container. I get the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'HOST_NAME' (110)"`

Where HOST_NAME is my actuall host name from the instance.
Has this something to do with ports or something?

Comment: I assume you are trying to use a variable named 'HOST_NAME', but from the error message it says it is trying to connect to a server with the address of 'HOST_NAME', so you aren't using the variable correctly.

Comment: Can you connect to MySQL from the host on which the docker container is running? Can you resolve the hostname of the MySQL instance from inside the Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by rebooting my containers en rebooting my Macbook.

I think the simple `boot2docker down` and `boot2docker up` does fix it.